# Android Gradle remove transitive dependency

Tags: android, gradle, transitive-dependency

I have an Android Project with gradle config like that:

MainApp: -dependOn-> Module T

MainApp: -dependOn-> Module C

Module C: -dependOn-> Module T

Now, I don't need Module T anymore in MainApp, so I remove it from MainApp, but when I build the project, I throw error because some class of Module C that extends from Module T can't be recognized in MainApp.

Can you help me how to remove Module T from MainApp

Answer (score 0):

Use `api` instead of `implementation` for `Module T` dependency in `Module C` `build.gradle` file

Comment: `api` would make dependency of module T available for MainApp in compile time. It's not good for build speed

Comment: The reason that I removed Module T from MainApp is:


Past:
`Module T` has class `SuperImageView`.
`MainApp` use `SuperImageView`.
`Module C` has class `ZoomableImageView` extends `SuperImageView`.


Now:
I don't want to use `SuperImageView` in MainApp anymore, so I removed it. But, when project is compiled, MainApp can't find the file `SuperImageView` so it throw Exception at build time.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to remove SuperImageView from your xml files @TrươngKhánh